# Python List not getting printed

Tags: python, list, nltk, stanford-nlp

I am stuck up on a pretty weird problem. Here is my code.

```
from nltk.parse.stanford import StanfordParser

stanford_parser_dir = 'stanford-parser/'
eng_model_path = stanford_parser_dir  + "stanford-parser-models/edu/stanford/nlp/models/lexparser/englishRNN.ser.gz"
my_path_to_models_jar = stanford_parser_dir  + "stanford-parser-3.5.2-models.jar"
my_path_to_jar = stanford_parser_dir  + "stanford-parser.jar"
parser=StanfordParser(model_path=eng_model_path, path_to_models_jar=my_path_to_models_jar, path_to_jar=my_path_to_jar)

a = list(parser.raw_parse("the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"))
print a
```

Nothing gets printed.

Now when I run the code using -i flag,like `python -i filename.py` and I try to `print a`, gives me the following error.

```
>>> a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

But now when I execute last two lines again in the same shell, it works fine..!

```
>>> a = list(parser.raw_parse("the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog"))
>>> print a
[Tree('ROOT', [Tree('S', [Tree('NP', [Tree('DT', ['the']), Tree('JJ', ['quick']), Tree('NN', ['brown']), Tree('NN', ['fox'])]), Tree('VP', [Tree('VBZ', ['jumps']), Tree('PP', [Tree('IN', ['over']), Tree('NP', [Tree('DT', ['the']), Tree('JJ', ['lazy']), Tree('NN', ['dog'])])])])])])]
```

Then why is not printing as output when I simply run the file using `python filename.py` ?

Comment: If you try to print "a" after just running "python filename.py" do you still get the error?

Comment: a cant be printed if only `python filename.py` is executed. We need to be inside the shell.

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Comment: Python 2.7.12, NLTK 3.2.1

Comment: How are you running the code? What OS and shell are you using (I'm not talking about the Python interpreter when I say "shell")?

Comment: Is the code you have printed exactly as what's in `filename.py`? Or is that a simplified version? There might have been other things like you mis-used `repr` vs `print` or you have broke the interface halfway through while waiting for the script to finish.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04, inside virtualenv. I am running the code in Ubuntu terminal.

Comment: Yes it is exactly the same code as it is in my file.

Comment: Remove `model_path=eng_model_path` argument from `StanfordParser()`

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not working.